# Morphisms of fibered categories which are compatible with the chosen cleavages

Tags: ct.category-theory, stacks, 2-categories, fibered-categories, grothendieck-construction

Let $\pi \colon F \rightarrow C$ and $\pi' \colon F' \rightarrow C$ be two fibered categories over the category $C$. A morphism from $\pi \colon F \rightarrow C$ to $\pi' \colon F' \rightarrow C$ is a functor $\phi \colon F \rightarrow F'$ such that $\pi' \circ \phi= \pi$ and $\phi$ maps any cartesian morphism to another cartesian morphism. This naturally defines a category $\rm{Fib}(C)$, the category of fibrations(fibered categories) over $C$, which is well known.

If we now define a new category $\rm{Fib}(C)_{cleavage}$, whose objects are pairs $(\pi \colon F \rightarrow C, K)$ where $\pi \colon F \rightarrow C$ is a fibration over $C$ and $K$ is a cleavage of $\pi$. A morphism from $(\pi \colon F \rightarrow C, K)$ to $(\pi' \colon F' \rightarrow C, K')$ is defined as a functor $\phi \colon F \rightarrow F'$ such that $\phi$ is a morphism of fibered categories(*defined in the previous paragraph*) and it is compatible with cleavages i.e $\phi(K(\gamma,p))= K'(\gamma,\phi(p))$ for all $(\gamma,p) \in \rm{Mor}(C) \times_{t,\pi_0,\pi_0} \rm{Obj}(F)$, where $t$ is the target map of $C$ and $\pi_o$ is the object level map of the functor $\pi$. It is easy to see that it defines a category.

**My questions are the following:**

(1) What are the advantages/disadvantages of the category $\rm{Fib}(C)_{cleavage}$ over the standard notion $\rm{Fib}(C)$?

(2) How (1) will affect the equivalence with the category of pseudofunctors over $C$?

**Just to be clear:**

I am aware of the notion of cloven fibrations(fibrations equipped with a choice of cleavage) over a category. But I am not sure/don't know any reference where they explicitly described the 1-morphisms and 2-morphisms of the 2-category of cloven fibrations over a category. Are 1-morphisms in this 2-category assumed to be compatible with the chosen cleavages(like the way I mentioned above) or they are just simply morphisms of fibered categories ?

*Thanks in advance.*

Comment: If you're working with choice, [there shouldn't be any difference](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/381676/is-ac-equivalent-over-zf-to-every-fibration-can-be-equipped-with-a-cleavage).

Comment: @AlecRhea Thanks for the link. I understand the point. But my confusion is about the "morphism of fibered categories compatible with the choices of cleavages". I think the usual forgetful functor may not be a full functor  $\rm{Fib}(C)_{cleavage} \rightarrow  \rm{Fib}(C)$, as all morphisms of fibered categories are not compatible with the cleavage choices.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure there are better references, but if you have none my [notes](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/351884844_Category_Theory) on researchgate address these topics from pages 193 onward. They aren't complete in any sense of the word, but should provide enough framework to understand what's going on.

Comment: Thanks for the notes link, I will go through it.