# Axiom of Choice for collections of Equinumerous sets

Tags: lo.logic, axiom-of-choice

Let ACE (Axiom of Choice for Equinumerous sets) be the following choice principal:

If $S$ is a set of non-empty sets such for any $X,Y\in S$ there is a bijection from $X$ to $Y$, then $S$ has a choice function.

I want to know if ACE implies AC or is strictly weaker.

**Motivation**

In the case of choice from families of finite sets, the analog of ACE is strictly weaker than AC, i.e. there is a model where for each $n$, every set of $n$-element sets has a choice function, but there is a countable collection of finite sets (of unbounded size) with no choice function.  You can get this by taking a permutation model with a set of $p$ atoms for each prime $p$, being acted on by the group $\prod_{p\text{ prime}} \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, with finite supports.

However, ACE implies every set of finite sets has a choice function.  To see this, suppose $S$ is a set of finite non-empty sets.  Then $\{X\times\omega | X\in S\}$ is a collection of countable sets, so has a choice function by ACE.  It's easy to build a choice function for $S$ from this.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

For any set $A$ and nonempty subset $B \subseteq A$, $B \times A^\omega$ is equinumerous with $A^\omega$: there is an injection from $B \times A^\omega$ to $A^\omega$ because $B \subseteq A$, and there is an injection from $A^\omega$ to $B \times A^\omega$ because $B$ is not empty, so by the Schröder-Bernstein theorem there is a bijection. By ACE, this implies there is a choice function on $\{B \times A^\omega | B \subseteq A\}$ (excluding the empty set), which implies there is a choice function on the power set of A (excluding the empty set), which is equivalent to the axiom of choice. So ACE implies AC.

Comment: Thanks; I thought it might be something simple like this but I couldn't think of it

Comment: Doesn't the proof of Schröder–Bernstein itself use choice?

Comment: No; it may be surprising but the definition of the function in Shroder-Bernstein does not use choice.

Answer (score 2):

*Au contaire*. Like all questions of this kind it depends on the wording.

Let $S$ be an inhabited set of inhabited sets, so we are **given** $x_0\in X_0\in S$.

If we are also **given** bijections $f_{X,Y}:X\cong Y$ for each pair $X,Y\in S$ then in particular we have $f_{X_0,Y}:X_0\cong Y$.

Therefore we have a defined element $y=f_{X_0,Y}(x_0)\in Y$ for each $Y\in S$.

No Choice required, if the question is understood in this way.

Indeed, by substituting "inhabited" for "non-empty", Excluded Middle is also avoided.

Comment: I don't understand this answer at all. It seems to me Brian Pinsky's question was quite clear, with no ambiguity how to read it.

Comment: The difference is in the meaning of "there exists", in particular when preceded by "for any".  The same issue applies to "a countable union of countable sets is countable", where the issue is whether the inner "countable" means that you have  *specified* enumerations $f_i:{\mathbb N}\cong X_i$. Of course, in a particular context, you might *not* intend "there exists" to mean that the thing is *given*.

Comment: This "ambiguity" only appears if you insist on reading the question constructively; since the resulting alternate interpretation of the question is trivial, I don't see the motivation for interpreting the question in this way. (IMO one of the strengths of classical quantifiers is that they let you unambiguously state what level of given-ness you want, the possible pathologies of minimal-givenness notwithstanding.)

Comment: But if you're going to follow the convention that saying “for all (…) there is (…)” means the data in question are *given*, then Choice itself is a triviality since “for all $X\in S$ there is $x\in X$” by this convention would mean that we are given a choice function. So yes, ACE doesn't require Choice with this convention, but Choice being true anyway, this is just “True implies True”.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Of course you know that various people disagree on what “constructive” means, but I should point out that not every constructivist thinks like Martin-Löf that “$\exists$” should mean “$\Sigma$” (see [this answer by Andrej Bauer](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/a/2450/2856)). In, say, the internal logic of a topos or in IZF, say, when you write “$\forall x\exists y$” this doesn't mean $y$ is given as a function of $x$. But I think Paul Taylor was making the point that people are sometimes sloppy in writing and actually *mean* this (I think OP was clear enough, though).

Comment: @NoahSchweber: *This "ambiguity" only appears if you insist on reading the question constructively*, or equivalently, if you insist on reading things unconstructively, you cannot see such distinctions. It's all about *precision* of language, which should be second nature for mathematicians. What you gain from such precision is a more delicate understanding of your subject.

Comment: A situation where this delineation makes a difference (and one that was ambiguous to me phrasing wise for awhile initially) is cleavages for fibrations in category theory; interpreting things as you suggest here would mean all fibrations are automatically cloven, and indeed the statement that ‘every fibration can be equipped with a cleavage’ is [equivalent over $ZF$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/381676/is-ac-equivalent-over-zf-to-every-fibration-can-be-equipped-with-a-cleavage) to choice (in the classical logic sense).

Comment: @Gro-Tsen: As Andrej says in the post that you cite,    "Mathematics needs both kinds of existence". In saying that it *depends on the wording* was drawing attention to these *two points of view*

Comment: @PaulTaylor I am sympathetic to your reasoning, but I think this answer is for a question that the OP wasn't asking. There's nothing in the question that indicates the OP is considering constructive logic or how that might impact what is more-or-less a classical set theory question. A debate around the constructive-sensitive phrasing is really not helping to answer the OP's question, is all I want to say.

Comment: @DavidRoberts: it was asked whether Choice was necessary, so the possibility that it is not was open. The question also postulated a system of bijections and as a freshman I was taught to "use all the hypotheses". This is what I did in my Answer. As for Constructivity, the community needs to be told repeatedly that it is "normal mathematics".

Comment: There are many mathematicians for whom AC is a point they are conscious of, and yet would never, never worry about LEM. If I were in your position, and felt motivated to add some constructive insight, one option would be for me to ask in a comment for clarification if such an answer would be of use to answer the OP's question. The OP in high probability a priori in this case would probably clarified that no, they didn't mean to call LEM into question. And as it happened, the answer with classical logic was what was needed. An alternative would be to up front and admit a constructivist answer..

Comment: ..was not requested by the OP, but in case others stumbling on this question later did in fact wish to work in a foundation without assuming LEM, here is an alternative perspective, for posterity. By starting one's answer with an "au contraire" it reads like telling the OP they are wrong, and this answer is the real answer to their real question they didn't even know they had. I'm not anti-constructive by any stretch of the imagination, but I wouldn't impose such an answer on someone who was not telling me that's what they wanted.

Comment: My job here is to help things run smoothly, not arbitrate about what "normal mathematics" is, even if I have my own Views on that. :-) Given the OP is happy with using Schröder–Bernstein as in the accepted answer that tells us that LEM is definitely assumed here, "ordinary mathematics" being secretly constructive or not.