# Can we show that a functor is a fibration without choosing a cleavage?

Tags: ct.category-theory, fibration, fibered-categories

> Is there a standard method for showing that a functor $F:\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{D}$ is a fibration, aside from constructing a cleavage?

In the proof of the Grothendieck construction, the fibration we obtain from an indexed category $\Psi:\mathcal{B}^{op}\to\mathfrak{Cat}$ is automatically cloven since we're constructing a specific Cartesian arrow $(u,1_{\Psi(u)(Y)})$ for each arrow $u:I\to J\in\mathcal{B}$ and object $(J,Y)\in\int\Psi$ above $J$.

Every time I want to show that a functor is a fibration, I end up constructing Cartesian arrows parametrized as above and thusly showing that it's a cloven fibration -- is this by necessity?

Any method of showing that a functor is a fibration without choosing a cleavage is welcome, but in particular something similar to the adjoint functor theorem for fibrations would be cool. That is, a statement along the lines of

> If $F:\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{D}$ is a functor and $\mathcal{C}$ is blah and $\mathcal{D}$ is bloop and $F$ preserves/reflects blorps then $F$ is a fibration.

Comment: Just as an example, given a category $\mathcal{C}$ with finite limits, showing $\mathrm{cod}\colon \mathcal{C}^\mathbf{2} \to \mathcal{C}$ is a fibration does not involve choosing a cleaving. Any time that one uses a universal property to show the existence of a cartesian lift, then you aren't exactly constructing a cleaving, since you don't have to specify precisely which item with the universal property you are using.

Comment: I'm thinking perhaps of the result at https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Grothendieck+fibration#in_terms_of_adjoints, where instead of asking that that the adjoint exists, one just has that an adjoint functor theorem is applicable. "Constructing"  the adjoint is probably equivalent to choosing a cleaving. If that answers your question, I can make it a proper answer.

Comment: @DavidRoberts But (in the codomain fibration example), when we say 'for an arrow $f:X\to Y$ in $\mathcal{C}$ and an object $g:Z\to Y$ in $\mathcal{C}^\to$ above $Y$, let [insert diagram] be a pullback of $f$ and $g$' then view the pullback diagram as an arrow above $f$ in $\mathcal{C}^\to$, haven't we chosen a specific pullback (even though there may be many isomorphic ones) and thusly chosen a cleavage? In other words, doesn't using a universal property to conjure up a specific instance of an object/arrows satisfying that property still amount to choosing a cleavage?

Comment: @DavidRoberts Your second comment looks more like what I'm looking for, thank you; please do convert it into an answer.

Comment: @AlecRhea: Showing that a pullback exists is different from choosing a pullback for every f, just like showing that a map is surjective is different from choosing a section (the latter requires the axiom of choice in general).

Comment: @DmitriPavlov But we aren't showing that a pullback exists, we're assuming $\mathcal{C}$ has pullbacks and then taking one specific pullback to be a Cartesian arrow in the arrow category. I typically carry out the argument this way at least; is it possible to phrase it in a way that avoids saying things like 'let [insert diagram] be a pullback of $f$ and $g$'?

Comment: @DmitriPavlov I guess we could say something like '$f$ and $g$ have a pullback since $\mathcal{C}$ has all pullbacks, and each pullback will be a Cartesian arrow over $f$ since for any coterminal...', so this apparent choice is maybe just an artefact of how I've been phrasing the argument.

Comment: I believe I've seen somewhere criteria in terms of properties of the diagonal functor $\mathcal C\to F/F$...

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე That would be interesting!

Comment: @DavidRoberts In light of the discussion above I think I was wrong, and your first universal property comment is a good example of what I'm looking for as well as the second comment, much appreciated.

Comment: @AlecRhea: there are two ways to say that a category $\mathcal{C}$ has pulbacks. As **structure**: there is a pullback-forming operation which takes a two arrows with a common codomain and gives a specific pullback diagram for them. As **property**: for any two arrows with a common codomain there *exists* a diagram which is a pullback of these arrows. If you use the latter, the codomain fibration twon't be cloven (unless you use the axiom of choice to can pass from property to structure).

Comment: @AndrejBauer This is the heart of the issue I was having, and addresses a question I couldn't put my finger on but have had for some time, thank you.

Comment: With that said, it is pretty rare to encounter non-cloven fibrations.  Most naturally-occurring categories with pullbacks have specified pullbacks -- at least, if Set does, which it does in ZFC and DTT, and you can choose to assume it does in ETCS.  The only examples I can think of offhand of categories with pullbacks but not specified pullbacks are where the morphisms are quotiented by something and the construction of a pullback depends on choosing representative morphisms, and it's rare for such quotiented categories to have pullbacks at all.

Comment: Also perhaps worth noting is that in homotopy type theory, any fibration between univalent categories is automatically cloven, because of the "unique choice principle" for functors.  So one might argue that the existence of non-cloven fibrations is an artifact of the formulation of category theory in set theory.

Comment: @MikeShulman That’s an interesting point, I was actually wondering if there were any fibrations that couldn’t be cloven in ZF, although I thought the Grothendieck construction would still go through so we should still have that every fibration is fibered equivalent to a cloven one right? And then the image of the cleaving for the Grothendieck side under the equivalence will be a cleaving for the original fibration?

Comment: The Grothendieck construction works, but it's the other direction that fails: without a cleaving, you can't make a fibration into a pseudofunctor.  As for whether there are any fibrations that can't be cloven in ZF, I believe the statement "all fibrations can be cloven" is equivalent to the axiom of choice: see the comment at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/243167/constructively-are-all-fibrations-cloven#comment599800_243187.

Comment: @MikeShulman Oh, duh (thank you), and you're correct about choice -- I actually asked that question [recently](https://mathoverflow.net/q/381676/92164). This obviously means that its consistent with ZF that all fibrations can be cloven (unless I'm mistaken), so none of them will be provably uncleavable.

Comment: Right, you won't be able to exhibit an uncleavable fibration unless you assume something that contradicts AC.  Although that only depends on the more obvious direction "AC $\Rightarrow$ all fibrations can be cloven".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just as an example, given a category $\mathcal{C}$ with finite limits, showing $\mathrm{cod}\colon \mathcal{C}^\mathbf{2}\to \mathcal{C}$ is a fibration does not involve choosing a cleaving. All that you need is that a pullback square *exists* for each piece of relevant data. A cleaving would be a specified choice of pullback square for each cospan.

More generally, any time that one uses a universal property to show the existence of a cartesian lift, then you aren't exactly constructing a cleaving, since you don't have to specify precisely which item with the universal property you are using.

I'm thinking also of the result at [the nLab page on Grothendieck fibrations](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Grothendieck+fibration#in_terms_of_adjoints):

> A functor $p \colon E \to B$ is a cloven fibration if and only if the canonical functor $i \colon E \to B\downarrow p$ has a right adjoint $r$ in $\mathbf{Cat} / B$.

where instead of asking that that the adjoint is given, one just has that an adjoint functor theorem is applicable. "Constructing" the adjoint is (probably) equivalent to choosing a cleaving.

Comment: I also generally recommend Streicher's notes on fibrations, in which he give a lot of material from Bénabou which was otherwise unpublished: _Fibred Categories à la Jean Bénabou_, https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.02927

Comment: A comment about my choice of terminology: the English word "cleaving" also translates to French "clivage" (if I trust DeepL and Google Translate) and is, to my mind, a better option than "cleavage".

Comment: It just occurred to me why cleaving might be a better choice when talking about this with my girlfriend, thank you for the recommendation haha.